# VBA Excel code stops execution after adding a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I seem to have stumbled upon a problem I can't seem to figure out how to solve. I'm currently working with 2 separate workbooks, one of them is the active workbook the code is run from, the other one is a separate workbook I need to open:

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:

Set manWb = ActiveWorkbook

Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
Set conWb = Workbooks.Open(PARDirOTC & PARFileOTC, ReadOnly:=False)
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI

ActiveWindow.Visible = False

On Error GoTo 0
```

I set the AutomationSecurity to msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable to prevent that second workbook from running its Workbook_Open event, which has code in it I don't need in this situation. That error handling event never seems to activate, and the code keeps going without issues.

Everything works nicely from this point on, I gather and exchange data between these 2 workbooks and nothing seems to go wrong. That is, until it gets to the point where I need to create a worksheet on the second workbook, the one called "conWb".

```
Set conOT = conWb.Sheets.Add(After:=conWb.Sheets(conWb.Sheets.Count))
```

This is the troubling line. The worksheet is created, but the code suddenly stops executing at this point. No error message at all, nothing pops up, it simply stops. I've noticed that the code apparently stops executing, and switches to the code in the newly created sheet, which is blank and has nothing in it. I can't understand why.

I've looked around, other people seem to have found similar issues, but none of their solutions worked for me. I've tried playing around with several Application settings, like EnableEvents, ScreenUpdating, AutomationSecurity, etc, but nothing works. Along the code, I've also tried to remove or comment out all of the "On Error" events, fearing that they could be hiding an error that could explain this behaviour, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

I'll highly appreciate if someone with more experience than me could help figure out what could be the reason for this behaviour. Thanks in advance.

Kind regards

Comment: If all you need is to prevent the `Workbook_Open` event, just use `Application.EnableEvents = False` rather than `AutomationSecurity`.

Comment: *"the active workbook the code is run from"* note that the workbook the code runs from is `ThisWorkbook` and not `ActiveWorkbook` which is the worbook that has the focus / is on top! `ActiveWorkbook` can switch to be any workbook the user clicks on while the code is running.

Comment: I noticed the same. Sometimes `.Sheets.Add(...` fails and breaks the module without error message, especially when a large amount of activities are queued somewhere. I wish someone knew a solution. BTW: `.Sheets.Add(..` activates the newly added sheet. It is not a fault, it is a feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Application.EnableEvents instead of Application.AutomationSecurity when opening the second workbook, like one of you suggested, ended up solving the entire issue. Like so:

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:

Set manWb = ActiveWorkbook

Application.EnableEvents = False
Set conWb = Workbooks.Open(PARDirOTC & PARFileOTC, ReadOnly:=False) 
Application.EnableEvents = True

ActiveWindow.Visible = False

On Error GoTo 0
```

As far as I know, AutomationSecurity can be used to disable all macros when opening a workbook programatically, and I thought that would be enough to prevent the Workbook_Open event, but I'm assuming that either there's some other event I wasn't aware of, or the AutomationSecurity setting works in a different way than what I initially thought.

Either way, the problem seems to be solved, so thank you.

Kind regards